# VBA Excel 2013 Copy certain information from one worksheet to anther worksheet - weekly reports

Tags: vba, excel

I'm super new to VBA and hope that someone can help. This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub Late()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MasterLastRow As Integer
    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim TrackingCount As Integer


    Worksheets("Master").Select
    Range("A4").Select

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set NewRange = Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If TrackingCount > 14 Then 
           'Copy row, col. A:M of "Master" worksheet into Col. A:M of "Late Report" worksheet
        End If
    Next i
```

Explanation: For each TrackingCount in Col Q of "Master" worksheet that is > 14, I need to copy only these rows, from columns A thru M and paste them into "Late Report" worksheet (beginning with A:3), one row after the other (for each one with TrackingCount > 14).

Once that's accomplished, I need to do the same thing when Tracking count is between 7 & 14 (to paste in the Late Report spreadsheet following the first report); then between 2 & 6 for a third report; and finally when =< 0 for the final report.

All reports need to paste one after the other. This is for a weekly report in which the the row counts will be different each week.

Comment: What are you holding in the "TrackingCount" variable? It's not being assigned in the sample you've shown.

Comment: Are all of the ranges going on the same sheet or is there a different sheet for each value range?

Comment: I'm holding the number of days that a job is past due.

Comment: The columns are the same in both worksheets, but the Late Report worksheet identifies the items by the number of days the job is late. The row count will change weekly b/c the jobs are updated weekly by the project managers.

Comment: If you're holding the number of days that a job is past due, where are you setting that value? Immediately after your `For i = 1 To LastRow` statement?

Comment: Setting the value...can you help me with do that? Like I said, I'm so new and struggling for now. I'm open to learn all I can.

Comment: Phil, I'm not even sure the For...Next loop is the best way to proceed. I'm trying to learn from other samples.

Comment: Is each report in a new Excel workbook or are you pasting to a new worksheet within the same workbook?

Comment: I'm pasting in a new worksheet called "Late Report" in the same workbook.

Comment: From "Master" to "Late Report"

Comment: Phil, did I answer your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's see if this is enough to get you started.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LateReport()
Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
Dim workingCell As Range
Dim workingRange As Range
Dim DestinationRow As Integer

Set MasterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' You may want to correct the name
Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' And for this as well


Set workingRange = MasterSheet.Range("A4:M4").CurrentRegion ' Adjust this starting point as required

For Each workingCell In workingRange.Columns(1).Cells ' We'll work our way down each cell in the first column

    If workingCell.Offset(0, 16).Value > 14 Then ' The Offset method looks at the cell X rows and Y columns away; in our case, 0 rows down and 16 columns across
        workingCell.Range(workingCell, workingCell.Offset(0, 20)).Copy ' Copy that row
        DestinationSheet.Range("A3").Offset(DestinationRow, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats ' Paste it to our destination
    End If

    DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1

Next

Set MasterSheet = Nothing
Set DestinationSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Some keywords**

`Option Explicit` is a must. It ensures that we don't get vague errors if we haven't declared our variables correctly.

The next one is the `CurrentRegion` property. That selects all the cells around the one we've defined (in this case, cells A4 through M4) that have a value. It's a quick and easy way to look at and work with a block of cells in a collection.

Your next task is to adapt this code to handle cases where the value in column "Q" is between 7 and 14, between 2 and 6, and less than or equal to 1 (which I'm assuming is a typo in your original question: you've said "0").

Good luck!

Comment: Phil, thank you so much! I've learned a lot and I'm almost there! But after it loops through a few iterations, I get error messages. I've made various changes, but still get taken to debug. Would you be willing to look at the file if I emailed it to you?

Comment: Why not. I'm feeling crazy enough today. Check my profile or visit http://wheeler.kiwi.nz for contact details.

Comment: Wow, very nice site. Wow! But do you have a private email address rather than social media? I didn't see your Google email address.

Comment: With the above code I get an Error 2015 the 2nd time it loops. "workingCell.Offset(0,16).Value = Error 2015". Any ideas?

Comment: I think that's a type mismatch where it's expecting a number or text value in the cell but that value is actually something else. Probably the offset value isn't right. We'd really need to see the sample data to make more informed guesses here.

Comment: You're right, Phil. In some cases, the dates in Col. G and Col. I are "None", producing a #VALUE! in Col Q. I think that is the only issue causing the error. Not sure how to resolve the type mismatch, but your are correct. Again, thank you so much for your fabulous help here. Once this is resolved, I'm sure that should do it!

Comment: Thank you Phil for your incredible help! I'm new to Stackflow; until my reputation reaches 15 I'm not allowed to upvote. I wish I could right now. Your answer is perfect and everything works perfectly! Thank you again, Phil!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the whole problem without the sheet, but it seems to me you try to copy a certain amount of rows that satisfy a requirement.

A more efficient way to program this is to first

- set a table in Excel using "Insert > Table".
- Then use Data > Filter to filter all rows that satisfy the requirement
- Then copy those rows
  (or part of the rows)

If you are unsure how to program this I recommend recording a macro. Also look into the Excel ListObject in VBA.